# play scala routes configuration

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play scala framework. I am trying to return dummy data based on the url entered. Please see below scenarios:

```
GET /test    ---> return fist test passed
GET /test/10   ---> return with param test passed
GET /test?id=10   ---> return with query param test passed

 other wise ---> return no test passed
```

In the routes, I have defined as below:

```
GET  /test/:key     com.test.controller.TestController.index(key: Option[String])
```

Controller:

```
def index[A](key: Option[String])  = Action {implicit request =>
    val test= key match {
      case Some(type :String)=> 
        Ok("first test")

      case None =>
             Ok("No test found")
    }
  }
```

In the controller I am not sure how to check for all the scenarios. Please help me in this

Comment: as you tagged, You really started playframework2.0? It's too old to use for fresh project. and answer will be different if you use 2.1 or newer one.

Comment: Can you please share any example for doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using Play 2.0 greater..

Routes file

```
GET  /test/:key     com.test.controller.TestController.index(key: Option[String])
```

Controller:

```
def index(key: Option[String])  = Action { implicit request =>
  key match {
    case Some(type :String)=> Ok("first test")
    case _ => Ok("No test found")
  }
}
```

Maybe this will do the work on your problem..